# MagicalRecord: how to cancel saveWithBlockAndWait?

Tags: core-data, ios7, magicalrecord-2.2

I've got a service call which then saves a lot of data after returning:

```
    [MagicalRecord saveWithBlockAndWait:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
        for (NSDictionary *dictionary in result) {
            // create managed object, set parameters
        }
    }];
```

Now if the user logs out during this for-loop, I would like cancel the saving - how is this achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `saveWithBlockAndWait` because it will still save even if you have code to exit the loop. Potentially you could reset the context before you exit, but you would need to carefully consider what side effects that could cause.

So, you want to run a block where you have control of the contents so you can check a flag while looping and exit the block without saving if the flag indicates a cancel.

Also, if you have so many items to save you should batch the save operation...

So, use `MR_saveToPersistentStoreCompletion` to save, but check a cancel flag first and return from the block if it's set:

```
localContext = NSManagedObjectContext.MR_contextForCurrentThread

[localContext performBlock:^{

    for (int i...) {

        ...

        if (i % 100 == 0) {
            if (!cancelled) {
                [context MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}];
```

Comment: how would such a block look like - including the batch operation, i.e. the saving operation?

Comment: thanks, one last question - does it make a difference if I use contextForCurrentThread or just MR_context? I would have said MR_context is more secure as MR_contextForCurrentThread possibly resets the data from other operations in the same thread as well

Comment: If you reset the context you mean? If you're going to reset then you probably want to create a context and never use it again after this. Then yes, MR_context would be good for that as it isn't cached.